# Restricting a function defined on an étale groupoid to an isotropy group

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, c-star-algebras, groupoids

Let  $\mathcal G$ be an étale groupoid,  let $x$ be a point in the unit space of $\mathcal G$,  and let $\mathcal G(x)$
be the isotropy group of $x$.

If $f$ is a continuous, complex valued, compactly supported function on $\mathcal G$, denote by $\rho (f)$ the restriction of $f$ to
$\mathcal G(x)$,  hence defining  a map
$$
  \rho :C_c(\mathcal G) \to  C_c(\mathcal G(x)).
  $$

I think I know how to prove that this map extends to a bounded, positive linear map
$$
  C^*(\mathcal G) \to  C^*(\mathcal G(x)),
  $$
where
$C^*(\mathcal G)$ is the  the full groupoid C$^*$-algebra,  and $C^*(\mathcal G(x))$ is  the full group C$^*$-algebra.

**Question**.  Can anyone provide a reference for this result?

In fact I'd be even happier if the reference covered  the case in which the groupoid is twisted and not necessarily
Hausdorff (with a Hausdorff unit space).

In the latter case one would, of course,  need to interpret
$C_c(\mathcal G)$ as is  usually done  when dealing with non-Hausdorff groupoids, while the group algebra of $\mathcal G(x)$
should  be replaced by its twisted version.

Finally, should you  know of a very slick way to prove it,  I would be interested in seeing it as well!