# Is it possible to characterize the elements of the C$^*$-algebra of an open subgroupoid?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, c-star-algebras, groupoids, amenability

$\newcommand{\Cstar}{C^*_{\text{red}}}\newcommand{\G}{\mathscr G}\newcommand{\H}{\mathscr H}$Let
$\G$ be an etale groupoid, let $U$ be an open subset  of $\G^{(0)}$, and let
$$
  \H = \{\gamma \in  \G: r(\gamma ), s(\gamma )\in U\}
  $$
be the reduction of $\G$ to $U$.

It is well known that any element of $\Cstar(\G)$ may  be seen as a function defined on $\G$, via a process resembling
the Fourier transform (ask me if you'd like more details on this).

Viewing elements of $\Cstar(\G)$  as functions, according to this,
it is not hard to see that every $f$ in the range of the natural embedding
$$
  \Cstar(\H) \hookrightarrow  \Cstar(\G)
  $$
vanishes off $\H$.

**Question**.  If $f$ is an element in $\Cstar(\G)$ vanishing off $\H$, can we guarantee that $f$ lies in the range of
the natural embedding above?

I am mostly interested in the case in which  $U$ is the complement of a point in  $\G^{(0)}$, so you are more than
welcome to assume this is the case.

I believe I know how to prove this in case $\G$ is amenable, or even if we simply assume that the full and  reduced
groupoid C$^*$-algebras of $\G$ coincide.  I am therefore really looking for a proof in the non-amenable case.

Just like my previous question ([Restricting a function defined on an étale groupoid to an isotropy group](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/389504/restricting-a-function-defined-on-an-%c3%a9tale-groupoid-to-an-isotropy-group)) whose bounty expired recently without any answer $\ddot\frown$, I'd be happier if the answer covered
the case in which the groupoid is twisted and not necessarily Hausdorff (with a Hausdorff unit space).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not an expert of groupoids and not sure what "Fourier coefficients" exactly means, but perhaps Wassermann's classical counterexample ([mr1127480](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1127480)) serve (against) the purpose?
Take an infinite residually finite Kazhdan (T) group $\Gamma$ with finite quotients denoted by $\Gamma_n$ and consider the unitary representation $\pi:=\bigoplus\lambda_n$ on $\bigoplus\ell_2\Gamma_n$.
Then, groupoids $\mathcal G$ and $\mathcal H$ can be constructed in such a way that
$$C^*_r{\mathcal G}=C^*(\pi(\Gamma))+\bigoplus B(\ell_2\Gamma_n)\subset B(\bigoplus\ell_2\Gamma_n)$$ and $C^*_r({\mathcal H})=\bigoplus B(\ell_2\Gamma_n)$
(or whole compact operators in place of the block-diagonal compact operators $\bigoplus B(\ell_2\Gamma_n)$).
Denote by $p_n$ the rank-one projection corresponding to $1_{\Gamma_n} \in \ell_2\Gamma_n$, which is the $\Gamma_n$-by-$\Gamma_n$ matrix with all entries $|\Gamma_n|^{-1}$.
Then the element $p:=\sum_n^\oplus p_n$ belongs to $C^*_r({\mathcal G})$ by property (T),
but not to $C^*_r({\mathcal H})$ although each "fiber" of $p$ does.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer and also for the suggestion to look at the case of group bundles.  This took me back to Rufus Willet's example of a non-amenable groupoid whose maximal and reduced C$^*$-algebras coincide (Münster J. of Math. 8 (2015), 241--252), which also provides a counter example to my question.  However Willet's example is based on $\mathbb F_2$, and his Remark 2.9.(i) seems to indicate that his construction will fail for $\text{SL}(3,{\mathbb Z})$, so I am still puzzling if a residually finite group with property (T) is the right choice.

Comment: In any case I am still studying your example which is perhaps not exactly along the same lines.

Comment: Regarding Fourier coefficients I guess I shouldn't have used that terminology since it is perhaps not standard.  All
I mean is that the evaluation maps $f\in C_c(\mathscr G) \mapsto  f(\gamma )\in {\mathbb C}$ extend continuously to $C^*_{\text{red}}(\mathscr G)$.